# How can I enter data to be columns of a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

Given to arrays `x` and `y`, how can I call `pd.DataFrames` so that x and y are columns and not rows?

I could do `pd.DataFrame( np.array([x,y]).transpose(), columns = list('ab') )` but there has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass a dictionary of arrays to the constructor's data parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=1000),
                        'b':np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=1000)})
print df.head()

   a  b
0  5  8
1  9  7
2  2  7
3  7  5
4  0  3
```